# Dynamically added draggable object not working the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I am adding the draggable functionality to an element on a particular user event(hold event). Drag functionality is not working the first time.

```
    Hammer(element).on("hold",function(event){
        console.log("hold");
        $(element).draggable({
                helper: "clone",
                cursorAt: { left: 5, top: -5 },
                cursor: "move",
                stop: function() {
                        $(element).draggable("destroy");
                }
        });
    });
```

In the above code snippet, the hold event triggers the draggable functionality but it only works when I release the hold and try it the next time. How can make the drag initiate on hold itself rather than the next time?

**EDIT:**

Added a sample code in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ayoqus/8/edit).

Comment: Could you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @apaul34208 Have posted an edit.

Comment: I played with this for a few hours it seems that the hammer plugin may be a little buggy. Best result with `"drag"` rather than `"hold"` still have to hit it twice, sorry I can't be more helpful

Comment: Just had a thought... It may be that you'll need to suppress the normal jquery-ui draggable mouse function in order to replace it with the hammer.js function. This may be why you're having to hit it twice.

Comment: looked around a little and found this touch plugin for jquery-ui http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Answer (score 1):

How about using a delay on the draggable instead of the hold Hammer event?

```
 $(element).draggable({
                helper: "clone",
                cursorAt: { left: 5, top: -5 },
                cursor: "move",
                stop: function() {
                        $(element).draggable("destroy");
                },
   start: function() {
     console.log("start");
   },
                delay:300
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$('.pic').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function(event, ui) {

    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).removeClass('dragging');
    }
});

$('body').hammer().on('hold', '.container li', function() {
    $('.pic', this).addClass('dragging');
});

$('body').hammer().on('dragstart', '.container li .pic', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('dragging')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

});
```